# Run parameter file using powershell on Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, shell

We have a file named as test which will contain below data.

```
export username=ganesh

export dept =hr

export job =developer
```

I need run this file from PowerShell , to initialize this variable.

I have tried  below code in Linux and it's working but in PowerShell prompt it's not working.

```
. /data/abcd/test>/dev/null 2>&1
```

**Note**: /data/abcd is folder

How can I achieve this from PowerShell?

Comment: AFAIK, PowerShell does not exist on Linux, which has [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: Hi, we have installed powershell in linux and it's working. we can use it with pwsh command

Comment: Basile, you've been able to install PowerShell Core on WIn/OSX/Linux for a few years now. As a matter of fact, the uptake on PowerShell Core is higher on Linux than on Windows. Resources: [powershell core download linux](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+core+downlad+linux&form=ANNTH1&refig=5c273a18dbd14dd290f63f82b0707348&sp=-1&pq=powershell+core+downlad+linu&sc=0-28&qs=n&sk=&cvid=5c273a18dbd14dd290f63f82b0707348)

Comment: Your file must have a .ps1 extension to run. When looking at the language syntax differences, try this cheat sheet as a starting point.  
 [BASH and PowerShell Quick Reference](http://www.cecs.wright.edu/~pmateti/Courses/233/Labs/Scripting/bashVsPowerShellTable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Export is a shell syntax but not a Powershell syntax, so you cannot source the file directly in Powershell. You have two options:

[1] Change the file name to something like "env-file.ps1" and modify the content to what Powershell can understand:

```
$Env:username = "ganesh"
$Env:dept = "hr"
$Env:job = "developer"
```

Then you can source the file and use the variables:

```
. ./env-file.ps1 
$Env:job
developer
```

Or [2] You can read in the file as is, dynamically convert the line to Powershell syntax, and then eval the line using `Invoke-Expression`:

```
foreach ($line in get-content env-file.env) {
   if ($line -match "(?ix)^ \s* export \s+ ([^=]+) \s* = \s* ([^=]+)$") {
      $cmd = '$Env' + ":" + $matches[1] + "=" + '"' + $matches[2] + '"'
      Invoke-Expression($cmd)
   }
}
```

After this you can use the variables:

```
$Env:username
$Env:dept
$Env:job
```

In other words, the code above serves as a complicated `source` on Unix export environment variable file.